# C++ error runing "hello world", vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"hello world!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run this simplest code in vs2010, but I received more than 100 errors when I was compiling it.

```
f:\vs2010\vc\include\fstream(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' 

f:\vs2010\vc\include\fstream(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

f:\vs2010\vc\include\fstream(16): error C2653: 'ios_base' : is not a class or namespace name

f:\vs2010\vc\include\fstream(16): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'openmode'

f:\vs2010\vc\include\fstream(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Errors like these. What should I do?

Comment: Does `int main() {}` compile?

Comment: @JunYu Zhou, I can assure you that the code is perfectly fine, there's something wrong with your compiler or with your libraries.

Comment: Go into your project properties page --> Linker --> System --> SubSystem and make sure its Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE). the code you posted runs & compiles just fine in VS2013, G++, and clang.

Comment: @Axalo no, it's the same result

Comment: @JunYuZhou he means *without* the include list or `using namespace std;`. **just** `int main() {}`

Comment: Do you have any other source files (.cpp) in your project?

Comment: @Freddy it's still the same result.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, it compiles

Comment: @Axalo Yes, there is one (.cpp) file

Comment: @JunYu Zhou, which is it ?

Comment: @ArunA.S I have deleted that one, but it stills produces those errors.

Comment: @JunYu Zhou, Why don't you try this. Close your VS2010. Open it again. Take a new Source File. Type the hello world code again. Then compile. ( Maybe it'll work, won't hurt to try )

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901869/how-can-i-create-a-c-project-solution-in-visual-studio-2010#3901898).

Comment: @ArunA.S I just tried and it was still the same. Btw, I can perfectly run C or C# program in VS2010

Comment: @Axalo No, it doesn't work. This thing drives me crazy.

Comment: @JunYuZhou What doesn't work?

Comment: @Axalo The way you just showed to me doesn't work.

Comment: @JunYuZhou I guess that means it doesn't compile. If so your installation of Visual Studio is bugged. Try to re-install it.

Comment: @Axalo Okay, it looks like that re-installing it is the only possible way to solve this problem now although all my C and C# programs can perfectly run in VS2010. Thanks.

Comment: I think there's a chance that the problem is with your iostream header, check it ( that's what I think from looking at your errors ).

Comment: @ArunA.S How do I update or replace my header files?

Answer (score -2):

try to include this lab in your code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: Error: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Comment: this mean you didn't install all C++ LAB correct so do this steps,  ,http://www.cs.utah.edu/~delisi/vsmpi/, just ignore 10-5 only and do all other steps